# How to fix cutscene audio stuttering?

Tags: technical-issues, torchlight-2

While the game itself runs smoothly and I can watch the cutscenes using the [bink player](http://www.radgametools.com/bnkdown.htm) without problems, their ingame playback fails to produce sound every other second (quite periodically actually). What's the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: What are your system specs? And I assume you use a motherboard based sound card right?

Comment: @Ids Yes, it's a Realtek onboard sound "card". But since neither the game's sound nor the directly played movies cause trouble, I'd be surprised if it was a hardware issue

Comment: onboard sound can stutter when the system is getting overloaded. Perhaps it keeps running torchlight in the background while playing the movie. That was why I asked.

Comment: @Ids interesting point, but I just checked and the movie plays fine via bink player even with Torchlight running in background. An AMD Phenom II X3 720 @ 2.8 GHz shouldn't have trouble with that anyway...

Comment: It's a [common problem](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=33858) and sometimes seems to be fixed by turning down shadows. The dev said he was going to look at it so it's most likely a bug of some sorts. [Another post](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bShowAll=true&bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=version&sTitle=&sReturnTo=&iId=26686) mentioned sound stuttering and fixed it by upping the priority of Torchlight (`nice` command for Linux, taskmanager can do that in Windows I believe).

Comment: @Aerus Thanks for the links. In addition to turning off the shadows I had to switch off bloom, then it worked indeed. Sounds like the menu/game is still rendered in background and interferes with the playback. It's still strange that I can even playback the video without stuttering using bink player while the game is running in the background, both fullscreen or windowed... Anyway, please make your comment an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in [this post](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=33858) on the Runic Games forums it's a known issue and quite a few people have a problem with it and the cause seems not known (yet), although a dev said he would look at the issue.

A first, *possible* solution is to turn down your `Shadows` setting. For some people this solves the problem. If this doesn't work, you can try to turn down other graphics such as `Bloom` (as mentioned by the OP) down aswell.

If this doesn't solve the problem either (or for people playing [Torchlight II on Linux in Wine](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bShowAll=true&bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=version&sTitle=&sReturnTo=&iId=26686) and having sound issues) it *can* help to increase the program's priority.
In Windows this can be done by simply launching Torchlight II and looking up `torchlight2.exe` in the `Processes` tab of the Task Manager. Once you found the process, right-click it and select `Set priority > High`.
In Linux this can be done by using the `nice` command to launch Torchlight II with Wine.

Comment: In my case, Bloom and Shadows had to be deactivated, while changing the process priority didn't do anything.

Comment: To save anyone else the trouble, I tried all of the above. Nothing worked. Still no solution to this I've been able to find at least.